# Delay in Loop occurs only once

Tags: swift, loops, sprite-kit

In my code I am trying to have it so the entity moves a certain number of times, and delays between each movement.

These movements are essential small teleports to allow for the movement distance to be slowed or speed up (that is what the RGBA part of the code does by using the green color at a pixel of another image that is not displayed).

The problem I am getting is that when a entity is moved.

It moves the correct distance, but all at once. Thus if I think I am telling it to move 10 units over 10 seconds, it waits 10 seconds then moves 10 units.

This is a problem as it looks bad and makes it so the entity "overshoots" where it is selected to go (that is what the "if" statement in the loop does, it stops the entity when it gets close).

Note: This function is within a class that is a SKNode.

Here is the code (note: "moveTo" is defined outside of the function):

```
 func moveGo(){
    var dX: CGFloat
    var dY: CGFloat
    var magnitudeOfVector: Double
    var originalX: CGFloat = self.position.x
    var originalY: CGFloat = self.position.y
    dX = ((moveTo?.x)! - (self.position.x))
    dY = ((moveTo?.y)! - (self.position.y))
    let wantedX: CGFloat = (moveTo?.x)!
    let wantedY: CGFloat = (moveTo?.y)!
    magnitudeOfVector = sqrt(((Double)(dX) * (Double)(dX) + (Double)(dY) * (Double)(dY)))
    dY = dY/(CGFloat)(magnitudeOfVector)
    dX = dX/(CGFloat)(magnitudeOfVector)
    var currentX = self.position.x
    var currentY = self.position.y
    for _ in 1...100{
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.1)
        if let (r,g,b,a) = pixel(in: image, at: self.position) {
            print ("Red \(r), Green: \(g), Blue :\(b), Alpha: \(a)")
            stepDebuff = 2*(CGFloat)(r)/255
        }
        dX = ((moveTo?.x)! - (originalX))
        dY = ((moveTo?.y)! - (originalY))
        dY = dY/(CGFloat)(magnitudeOfVector)
        dX = dX/(CGFloat)(magnitudeOfVector)
        dY = dY * defaultStepSize * stepDebuff
        dX = dX * defaultStepSize * stepDebuff
        currentX += dX
        currentY += dY
        self.position = CGPoint(x: currentX, y: currentY)
        if abs(wantedX - currentX) < 2 && abs(wantedY - currentY) < 2{
            if abs(wantedX - currentX) < 0.01 && abs(wantedY - currentY) < 0.01{
                dY = 0
                dX = 0
            } else{
                dX = ((moveTo?.x)! - (self.position.x))
                dY = ((moveTo?.y)! - (self.position.y))
            }
        }
        print("\(magnitudeOfVector)")
        print("\(dX)")
        print("\(currentX)")
    }
}
```

The number of loops is arbitrary. defaultStepSize = 1.

Comment: What Swift version is this? It certainly isn't valid Swift 3

Comment: It is swift 3. The strange optional syntax is because I do not know how to make the code stop worrying that the optional might be a nil (I have an earlier function that checks to see if the "moveTo" is nil before starting this one).

Comment: It does run, and I updated XCode a few days ago. It might be that my syntax is terrible.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention it is within a class. That is probably why it looked so strange.

Comment: `dY = dY/(CGFloat)(magnitudeOfVector)` this isn't valid swift, for example

Comment: But yeah, it kinda is. You should clean up the force unwraps, use compound  assignment operators, and avoid needless forward declaration and mutability.

Comment: You are completely misusing `SKAction`. `SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.1)` creates an instance which should be performed later with `run` method, but in your code it is disposed without running. You need to create a sequence action containing wait actions and moveTo actions, and then run the sequence action. Do not directly manipulate the `position` property.

Comment: How would I preserve the ability to sample every point the entity goes over to dynamically change its movement speed if I do not directly manipulate the position property?